# I am getting error message during Android plugin in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature,23.0.7.2120684.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature,23.0.7.2120684.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature,23.0.7.2120684.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature,23.0.7.2120684.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature,23.0.7.2120684.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature,23.0.7.2120684.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
```

Comment: It tells you: `Check the server`, which is probably **dead**. Unfortunately, `Eclipse is no longer supported`. The only way you could hope to revive an Eclipse IDE is to copy the exact installation from another machine (and make the exact paths or change them manually in every single configuration file - which I would not recommend).

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Eclipse for developing android applications, use Android Studio instead, now it is the official IDE for developing android applications.